# How to do string comparison condition in DOS?

Tags: windows, command-line, dos

Wow, never thought I would ever write anything in DOS. Now that I do, I know why I never wanted to. The syntax is absurd!

Anyways I need help please. 
I would like to prompt the user for input, and if a blank line is received, I would like to use the default value, like this:

```
set name=abraham.
set /p input=please enter your name, press enter to use %name%:
if not %input%=="" set name=%input%
echo your name is %name%
```

I get an error says "set was unexpected at this time."

Can you help please?

Comment: I'm just curious -- why do you suddenly *have* to program in DOS?  Can't you just write a Java/C#/etc. console program that would be infinitely easier to write?

Comment: it's used to automate a project deployment that involves many steps, which due to security and geographical reasons, sometimes we have to instruct the customer to do it over the phone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
set name=abraham
set /p name=please enter your name, press enter to use %name%:

echo entered : %name%
```

Note that in cmd files, if nothing is entered, the var is not changed.

Or, with the if:

```
set name=abraham
set input=
set /p input=please enter your name, press enter to use %name%:
if "%input%" NEQ "" set name=%input%
echo entered : %name%
```

Note the quotes around input in the if statement, and notice that I am clearing out input before running (or it will hold the last value if nothing is entered by the user)

Comment: omg! should have posted question before I put so much time into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Empty strings are actually empty in shell programming, so try `if "%input%"=="" set...` (with quotes) or `if %input%== set...` (empty string is empty).

Comment: sorry for the lolcat reference but i just could not resist >_<

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to put single quotes (not sure if double or single matter) around the variable:

```
@echo off
set name=abraham.
set /p input=please enter your name, press enter to use %name%:
if not '%input%'=='' set name=%input%
echo your name is %name%

pause
```